# Adding Boolean variable to my entity crashes application

Tags: sql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I tried adding new class to my application. Everything was fine, until I added `Boolean read`. When I add it to my class, I get:

`We got the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read tinyint(1) default 0, constraint ck_event_type check (' at line 7 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000], while trying to run this SQL script:`

and the important part of the script:

```
create table event (
id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
type                      varchar(14) not null,
user_id                   bigint,
message                   varchar(255) not null,
date                      date,
read                      tinyint(1) default 0,
constraint ck_event_type check (type in ('game_started','game_completed','wrong_answer','correct_answer','wrong_location')),
constraint pk_event primary key (id))
```

I have no idea what's the problem. I have Boolean declared in other class and there is no problem. I'm using play 2.2.1

My class:

```
package models;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

@Entity
public class Event extends Model{

@Id
public Long id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(nullable = false)
public EVENT_TYPE type;

@ManyToOne
public User user;

@Column
public Date date;

@Column(nullable = false)
public String message;
@Column
public Boolean read;


public Event(User user, String message, EVENT_TYPE type, Date date) {
    //this.user = user;
    //this.message = message;
    //this.type = type;
    //this.date = date;
    //read = false;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` is a reserved keyword in MySql. Try naming that column something else.

[Reserved Words in MySQL 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-7.html)